# Altering PHP Variable Based Off Selection

Tags: php, html, joomla3.1

I have a html select that holds values for all four of our offices, or the text All.  If the user selects All, I want to echo "All Offices", but if the user selects a specific office, I want to echo that number.  My problem is that when I run the syntax below, All remains All instead of All Offices.

Did I set this up the incorrect way?

```
Display Data For Which Office:
<select name="office">
    <option value="All">All...</option>
    <option value="one">One Quarter</option>
    <option value="two">Two Quarter</option>
    <option value="three">Three Quarter</option>
    <option value="four">Four Quarter</option>
</select>


<?php
    if ($officename != 'All') {
        $officename = $_POST['officename'];
    } else {
        $officename = "All Offices";
    }

    echo $officename;
?>
```

Comment: You need to make an HTML form first. Google how to do html form submission in PHP.

Comment: Is this the full code? Or a snippet? Or multiple snippets put together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialized the `$officename` variable, so it should be null. As a result, won't `$officename != 'All'` always be true, so `$officename = $_POST['officename'];` will always be executed?

I think what you want instead is something like:

```
$officename = $_POST['officename'];

if ($officename == 'All') {
    $officename = "All Offices";
}

echo $officename;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're wanting "All" to come from the value of the `<select>`, which is named "office". Therefore you need to assign that value to a variable before you can use it for comparison. Note the select is named "office" not "officename", so it's "office" you need to look for in `$_POST`.

```
$officeValue = $_POST['office'];

if ($officeValue == 'All') {
    $officename = "All Offices";
}
else {
  $officename = $_POST["officename"]; //I assume this is some other field in the form which you haven't shown, but which contains a human-readable office name.
}

echo $officename;
```